# I can't get my hooks to work in React Native, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I'm making an app to compare battery usage between GPS and Inertial Navigation(INS), and i've made the GPS app. Now when i'm making this INS app i can't get the logic to work the way i want it to. Im not super used to react native but thought i would be experienced enough, little did i know that functional components is the new thing which i cna't really get to work the way i want it to. I got it to "work" earlier by using the maps update interval as a dependency for the hook but the map can only update once every second at it's fastest pace, which was a tad bit too low for the use case i got. So the issue i'm having is that my hook to update the values arent updating the values. The hook that updates the geolocation, accelerometer and gyroscope values work, but the one that is supposed to calculate speed and angle from said values doesn't work at all..

```
// Map Screen
const MapScreen = () => {
    // Coordinates
    const [latitude, setLatitude] = React.useState(0);
    const [longitude, setLongitude] = React.useState(0);

    // Toggle for map update
    const [count, setCount] = React.useState(true);

    //Center map on user
    const [centerOnUser, setCenterOnUser] = React.useState(false);

    // Measured coordinates
    const [startLat, setStartLat] = React.useState(-1);
    const [startLong, setStartLong] = React.useState(-1);
    const [endLat, setEndLat] = React.useState(-1);
    const [endLong, setEndLong] = React.useState(-1);

    //INS Speed and Distance
    const [speed, setSpeed] = React.useState(0);
    const [distance, setDistance] = React.useState(0);

    //INS Rotation and Direction
    const [rotation, setRotation] = React.useState(0);
    const [direction, setDirection] = React.useState(0);

    // Init coords
    React.useEffect(() => {
        // Get initial Coordinates from GPS
        Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            (position) => {
                setLatitude(position.coords.latitude);
                setLongitude(position.coords.longitude);
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log(error);
            },
            { enableHighAccuracy: true }
        );

        // Subscribe to accelerometer data and measure speed and distance
        const accelSub = accelerometer.subscribe(({ x, y, z }) => {
            setSpeed(parseFloat((speed * 0.94 + ((Math.abs(x) + y + z) - 9.82) * 0.06).toFixed(2)));
        });

        //Subscribe to gyroscope data and measure direction and rotation
        const gyroSub = gyroscope.subscribe(({ z }) => {
            setRotation(parseFloat((rotation * 0.9 + z * 0.1).toFixed(2)));
        });

        return () => {
            accelSub.unsubscribe();
            gyroSub.unsubscribe();
        }
    }, []);

    // Update coords on map on user movement
    React.useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            //Measures Acceleration from Accelerometer to measure Distance
            setDistance(parseFloat((distance + (speed * 5)).toFixed(2)));
            //Measures Rotation from Gyroscope to measaure Direction
            setDirection(parseFloat((direction + (rotation * 5)).toFixed(2)));
        }, 1000);
        return () => {
            clearInterval(interval);
        };
    }, []);

    var myRegion = {
        latitude: latitude,
        longitude: longitude,
        latitudeDelta: 0.2,
        longitudeDelta: 0.2
    };

    // Returns View
    return (
        <View>
            <View>
                <Button title="Start measurement" onPress={() => {
                    setCenterOnUser(true);
                    setStartLat(latitude);
                    setStartLong(longitude);
                }} />
                <Button title="Stop measurement" onPress={() => {
                    setCenterOnUser(false);
                    setEndLat(-1);
                    setEndLong(-1);
                }} />
                <MapView
                    region={myRegion}
                    style={{ top: 0, left: 0, height: 450 }}
                    showsUserLocation={true}
                    userLocationUpdateInterval={1000}
                    onUserLocationChange={() => {
                    }}
                />
            </View >
            <View>
                <Text>
                    Starting Coordinates:
                </Text>
                <Text>
                    Latitude: {startLat}       Longitude: {startLong}
                </Text>
                <Text>
                    Ending Coordinates:
                </Text>
                <Text>
                    Latitude: {endLat}        Longitude: {endLong}
                </Text>
                <Text>Distance: {distance}</Text>
                <Text>Speed: {(speed * 3.6).toFixed(2)}</Text>
                <Text>Rotation: {rotation}</Text>
                <Text>Direction: {direction}</Text>
                <Text>{centerOnUser ? 'measuring' : 'waiting'}</Text>
            </View >
        </View>
    )
};
```

Comment: what is the issue you are facing ?

Comment: The issue is that the values of rotation and direction aren't getting updated, they stay at 0 although a console.log shows up in the console, but logs 0 on them. The values of speed and rotation are constantly updated and both works in console logs and in the rendered part on the app. I want to update the direction and rotation faster than my current solution, which is limited by the maps lowest update frequency of 1000ms